# Get window name of byobu session in bash

Tags: bash, window, byobu

is there a way to get the byobu window number (or window name) in shell?

I want the same code to behave differently depending on the window in which it is running: I am thinking about something like this (searched is getByobuWindowNumber()):

```
$/bin/bash
windowName=getByobuWindowNumber()

if ($windowName=="1")
then
    infile="infile1.txt"
fi

if ($windowName=="2")
then
    infile="infile2.txt"
fi

do.something($infile)
```

Thanks in advance.

Mathias

Comment: welcome to askubuntu! This isn't my strongest suit, but have you reviewed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu specifically the section on screen - manual here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/screen.1.html

Comment: Hey, I found an answer in the meantime. I will post it as an answer

Comment: Feel free to post your answer as an answer rather than a comment so that others in your situation can find it and be possibly helped by it. Please be as thorough in your answer as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer in the meantime. I hope it will be helpful for anyone else seeking help on this topic:

It is possible to get the session number via environmental variable `TMUX_PANE`; just get it via `windowName=$TMUX_PANE`; this is it :). Integrated in the code example above:

```
#!/bin/bash
windowName=$TMUX_PANE

if [[ $windowName == "%1" ]]
then
    infile="infile1.txt"
fi

if [[ $windowName == "%2" ]]
then
    infile="infile2.txt"
fi

do.something($infile)
```

Btw, there is an environmental variable `$BYOBU_WINDOW_NAME`. But on my system it is not set properly (all the same in all windows, although windows have been named differently by myself). But the solution above works anyway ...